# enter priviledge executive mode in php code via ssh and exec commands

Tags: php, ssh, cisco, phpseclib

I am writing a php code that connects to a cisco router via ssh.
I am facing a problem (returning null) when getting the interfaces' info.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec('enable');
$ssh->read('Password:');
$ssh->write("password\n");
echo $ssh->read();
$a=$ssh->exec('show run | include interface');
```

$a (the show command) is returning null.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `show run | include interface` supposed to run after `enable`? Is `Password:` supposed to be a prompt of the `enable` command? Assuming the answers to those questions are yes and yes then I think this is more along the lines of what you're wanting to do:

```
$ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("enable\n");
$ssh->read('Password:');
$ssh->write("password\n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("show run | include interface\n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
```